# Can the BREAK ON statement in Oracle be used in PHP?

Tags: php, oracle11g

I can use SQL*Plus with `BREAK ON` fine, but I don't get any results or errors with php.

Can the `BREAK ON` statement be used in PHP (or other language)?  Is it SQL*Plus only?  Fails in SQL Developer as well

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12009.htm

Here is an example query from the link.  I am using PDO if it matters.

```
BREAK ON DEPARTMENT_ID ON JOB_ID DUPLICATES
COMPUTE SUM OF SALARY ON DEPARTMENT_ID
COMPUTE AVG OF SALARY ON JOB_ID
SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID, JOB_ID, LAST_NAME, SALARY
FROM EMP_DETAILS_VIEW
WHERE JOB_ID IN ('SH_CLERK', 'SA_MAN')
AND DEPARTMENT_ID IN (50, 80)
ORDER BY DEPARTMENT_ID, JOB_ID;
```

(I read the page and saw references to SQL*Plus and nothing else.  Maybe I'm missing it.  It didn't say I can't use something other than SQL*Plus that I could find.  I know it is the SQL*Plus User Guide.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BREAK ON` and `COMPUTE` are both SQL*Plus commands.  They will only work in SQL*Plus or some other front-end that happens to implement those SQL*Plus commands.  If SQL Developer doesn't implement those, I would doubt that any other tool would.

It looks like you would want to do some sort of [`GROUP BY ROLLUP`](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets.php#rollup) in your SQL statement to get the subtotals you want.